# iPhone 3G with iOS 4.1 reboots while debugging

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I'm using Xcode 3.2.4.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Here's the console message that I had gathered:

```
10/22/10 10:53:58 PM     Xcode[70765]     _NotificationSocketReadCallback (thread 0x1170b0000): Unexpected connection closure...
10/22/10 10:53:58 PM     Xcode[70765]     Got faceplant notification
10/22/10 10:53:58 PM     Xcode[70765]     AMDServiceConnectionSendMessage (thread 0x1170b0000): Could not send message size: Broken pipe
```

I was able to see a glimpse of the app launching while debugging, but then it reboots.

Xcode reports these error messages:

```
   gdb stack trace at 'putpkt: write failed':
   putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe
   putpkt: write failed: Broken pipe
   The program being debugged is not being run.
   The program being debugged is not being run.

0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0018d893 remote_backtrace_self + 54
1   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00190cab putpkt_binary + 401
2   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0019661e remote_macosx_create_inferior + 1005
3   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0006f611 run_command_1 + 660
4   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0012ed92 execute_command + 713
5   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0001bbcb mi_execute_async_cli_command + 226
6   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0001b1e8 captured_mi_execute_command + 371
7   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000850d3 catch_exception + 65
8   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00018546 mi_execute_command + 163
9   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000186eb mi_execute_command_wrapper + 50
10  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008aab5 handle_file_event + 349
11  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008a47c process_event + 131
12  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008b236 gdb_do_one_event + 1178
13  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000851f6 catch_errors + 78
14  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008a92d start_event_loop + 76
15  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000876a3 captured_command_loop + 18
16  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000851f6 catch_errors + 78
17  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0008768f captured_main + 5557
18  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000851f6 catch_errors + 78
19  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000860cf gdb_main + 63
20  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00001b6a main + 52
21  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x00001af9 start + 53
```

Update: I have confirmed that this issue only occurs on jailbroken devices.

Comment: damn... I just got the same issue. It reboots the device and after that it run just fine.  dandy...

Answer (score 0):

Same here. It seems there's a bug whit Xcode (and some other stuff) with the JB. 
If you look at the comments here: http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/1359246784/20102010-event#idc-cover you can see there's people reporting the same.

I haven't found the solution, so i guess we'll have to wait until 4.2 comes up. :(

I work making iPhone apps and, it's really anoying T_T

Comment: It's not Xcode problem. I suspect it's the problem of this version of jailbroken firmware. I see various reboots as well on the jailbroken phone.