# Jailbroken iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1 can't be debugged with XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to debug my applications with XCode 3.2.5 and jailbroken iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1.

When I start debug **with** enabled breakpoints, application can't start (it stucks on 'Default.png' screen) and I get *Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Can't find dlopen function, so it is not possible to load shared libraries.)* message in GDB.

When I start debug **without** enabled breakpoints, application starts without problems.

I tried to do steps decribed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031735/got-stuck-with-an-error-application-exits-with-following-error-message-in-consol/4031778#4031778), but without any results.

When I used iOS 4.1 there was a problem with [reboots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999164/iphone-3g-with-ios-4-1-reboots-while-debugging).

On **every** connect of the iPhone Organiser displays this message:

`**Unknown iOS detected** Xcode does not have debugging information for the version of iOS on the device named “iPhone”. Xcode can collect debugging data from the device to enable development with this version of iOS. This process only needs to be done once per iOS version, and will take several minutes.`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the risk of jailbreaking.

Comment: This problem seemed to be fixed at some point before Xcode 4.0.2, as my iPhone 3G was working beautifully. That was until I updated to Lion and Xcode 4.1, the problem was there again.

See this other question for additional info:

- http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18876/xcode-4-1-stuck-trying-to-load-debug-symbols-from-iphone-3g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jailbroken 3GS / 4.2.1

I tried Matthew Frederick's recommendation without success.  Anyone happened to find a solution to this problem?

---

EDIT

Please note that I used a jailbroken **3GS** and a non-jailbroken **3GS**.
Workaround, requires a **non-jailbroken iPhone 3GS with 4.2.1 (8C148a)**:

1. Delete /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)
2. Connect the non-jailbroken iPhone 3GS with 4.2.1 (8C148a)
3. Open Xcode and Organizer
4. Configure the new iPhone for development by clicking the "Use for development" button in the Organizer.
5. Let it extract the debugging symbols from it recreating /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)
6. Unplug it, remove from Organizer

At this point you can debug your jailbroken iPhone again.
Cheers!

Comment: I tried with non-jailbroken iPod4 and jailbroken iPhone 3G (both are running 4.2.1). Looks like only the same devices can be used for this trick. So I'm going to find somebody with non-jailbroken iPhone 3G in my city :)

Comment: Jorge, could you try one thing? Could you, please, put a breakpoint and reach that code? Because I can start my application with breakpoints now (after your advice), but than an application reaches a breakpoint I get the same message 'Data Formatters temporarily unavailable....'

Comment: Vitaly, I'm not getting that specific warning but it might be that /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/CFDataFormatters.dylib is missing.  Try copying that file from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/Developer/usr/lib to see if you can get rid of it.  That might solve the warning problem but could cause other problems.

Comment: Vitaly, have you found non-jailbroken iPhone 3G? If so - can you upload files to any file sharing service and post a link? Or send them directly to my_first_name.my_second_name@gmail.com (names from account :))

Comment: Can anyone in this thread post up a cloud.ly or droplr link to a zipped 4.2.1 Symbols folder?

Comment: @JustinAmberson do you still need the symbols folder? I might be able to get thme if you really need them.

Comment: Yes, please, I will save them in Dropbox to have them forever =)

Comment: @JustinAmberson I just contacted you via Twitter. The symbols are around 350Mb and don't want to post a dropbox link here.

Comment: You did? I'm @justinxxvii on Twitter, I don't see any mentions from that time frame.

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that your problem can be solved by reauthorizing your device:

1. If your iPhone is plugged into the computer, **unplug it**
2. In Xcode, **display the Organizer** (Window->Organizer)
3. In the **Devices** area click on your device and **delete it**.
4. Just in case, **Quit Xcode** and then **re-launch** it.
5. Open the Organizer again, then **plug your iPhone** into your computer.
6. Tell Xcode that yes, you'd like to **authorize the device**.
7. If everything works correctly, Xcode will now **download device information** for 4.2.1.

If this doesn't work then I suggest performing the steps again, but replace step 4 with removing all traces of Xcode from your computer and then reinstalling it. This includes the entire Developer folder.

Comment: Might need more thorough cleaning. A clean install of Snow Leopard? That will just waste my time.

Comment: You might not have fully uninstalled Xcode. It's essential that you open Terminal and enter `sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` in order to actually remove all of the low-level stuff.

Comment: I already uninstall with the following steps: unixdev, systemsupport, and all. The data is kept somewhere else, I suppose. The deviceinfo file in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Devices has been removed too.

Comment: Supposedly if you don't uninstall it via the command line like that, stuff will be left behind that will keep you from having an actual fresh install.

Comment: I know. I always uninstall with command line. For example, Xcode 4 uninstall with --mode=all doesn't uninstall unixdev and systemsupport. So, I also tried to uninstall unixdev and systemsupport, and afterwards all. When I download the device symbols, it still could not download them (only dyld is on the Symbols folder).

Comment: Hmm. Well, the only obvious thing left is to restore your device to it's non-jailbroken state and try again.

Comment: I won't be able to activate it then. I jailbreak the device to be able to unlock and activate it, not just for hacking.

Comment: Note an edit was suggested (and rejected) http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3162543

Answer (score 5):

The latest Xcode+SDK drop doesn't know about iOS 4.2.1, because it was published before the latest patch came out. Xcode's Organizer has a new feature that tries to download debug support files directly from the device, but apparently it has some (possibly jailbreak-related) issues for some people.

iOS 4.2.1 is similar enough to 4.2 that Xcode can be coerced to use 4.2 support files to debug on 4.2.1 devices. To do this, simply go to the `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` folder and manually copy the `Symbols` subfolder and/or the `DeveloperDiskImage.*` files from `4.2 (8C134)` to `4.2.1 (8C148)` (or whatever release folder Organizer creates for your device).

Comment: This worked in my case. I had jailbroken iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1 on it. Thanks!

Comment: After this Organizer detects iPhone as debug-enabled device, but the real debug can't be started. Program stucks on splash screen. 

In GDB I can see such messages:
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox

Answer (score 1):

In order to get rid of (Re)Collecting Debug Symbols in Organizer (which in fact does nothing) each time the iPhone is presented to the XCode, a simple workaround is to copy:

DeveloperDiskImage.dmg and DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature

from the 4.2 (8C134) to the empty 4.2.1 (8C148) folder.

The XCode will recognize device and you'll be able to debug your code, but without debug symbols for the IOS framework.
But, the gdb console will be alive and you can use it do debug your code (with debug symbols).

Btw. you can always use Simulator for the full IOS support :-)

Answer (score 0):

My completely non-Jailbroken iPhone does this with 4.2.1, and gets exactly the same messages and problems. It's new functionality in the latest version of XCode, so it may well be buggy.

Comment: I like that you said 'functionality' :)

Answer (score 0):

Additional suggestion besides Fnord's suggestion is to make sure that multitasking, or the "Reenable Functionality" in PwnageTool is not enabled for iPhone 3G jailbroken device.

I'm not sure if this has an effect though. But, it's reasonable to do this if we really want to test it on a real world condition of iPhone 3G.