# Weird iPhone error when running on device

Tags: iphone, ios

I've run this app on my iPhone before, and I have no idea how it randomly started not working, but I'm getting the following error:

Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

So, I cleaned all targets and then deleted the app on my device and reinstalled it and ran it, and now I'm getting this error:

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try unplugging your device and reconnecting it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have the same problem but it only disables debugging (doesn't find the debugger symbols of the version installed on the device). Except debugging, It installs the app normally.
I know few people who got rid of these warnings by doing any of the following two :

1) copy the 4.2.1 symbols folder from the /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ path to the symbols fodler in 4.2.1 (8C148) folder

2) Look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432886/jailbroken-iphone-3g-with-ios-4-2-1-cant-be-debugged-with-xcode/4476225#4476225)

Answer (score 0):

Universal fix is: 'Clean all' in your project, delete app from device. Rebuild.

Comment: warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

Comment: 1. check all your frameworks are being setup correctly. 2. reboot xcode :)

Comment: Oh, yes. And sometimes rebooting device also helps. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting the same version that you're running on the device? Check this, then clean, delete from app, and rebuild.

Comment: unless you need the newest API features, try falling back to iOS 4.2 as the development target. Get info on your project, then under general, set "Base SDK for All Configurations" to iOS 4.2.