# Unable to connect jailbroken iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1 to Xcode for development

Tags: iphone, xcode, jailbreak, organizer

I have jailbroken iPhone 3G and recently I've updated the firmware to 4.2.1 (was 3.1.2). Now I'm trying to add this iPhone to Xcode organizer to use it for development. Xcode runs the process of collecting debug information for the device but gets stuck copying file (2 of 2) somewhere about 80%. I switch to Console and see nothing that could relate to the problem. Where can I get more information about what's happeining?

*Update:*
I've tried to reconnect the device and this time there is multiple lines in Console:

```
Sun Nov 20 02:13:57 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2ffea000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from DTDKSymbolHelper. Killing connection
Sun Nov 20 02:13:57 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message
Sun Nov 20 02:13:57 unknown /Developer/Library/Daemons/DTFetchSymbols[1859] <Notice>: Found paths:
Sun Nov 20 02:13:57 unknown /Developer/Library/Daemons/DTFetchSymbols[1859] <Notice>: /usr/lib/dyld
Sun Nov 20 02:13:57 unknown /Developer/Library/Daemons/DTFetchSymbols[1859] <Notice>: /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv6
Sun Nov 20 02:14:59 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2ff68000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from MDCrashReportTool. Killing connection
```

Googling did not give any results.

Comment: What version of Xcode ? What SDK are you using ?

Comment: If your iPhone is Jailbroken, you may wanna try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432886/jailbroken-iphone-3g-with-ios-4-2-1-cant-be-debugged-with-xcode/4476225#4476225)

Comment: it's a good quest - find non jailbroken iPhone3G[s] with iOS4.2.1)) but thank you very much for the link. my iPhone  is really slightly jailbroken))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an SDK installed on your desktop that supports the iOS version installed on your iPhone. Otherwise, Xcode will not recognize your device. You can also launch Organizer and it will tell you whats going on and if your device (OS) is supported.

Comment: that is the reason - xCode tells it knows nothing about iOS installed on connected iPhone and offers to collect debugging information from device. When it's trying to get this info it stucks. I've look into /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ant found 4.2 and 4.3 and no 4.2.1 between them.

Comment: Your device needs to have an iOS that is installed on your desktop, otherwise you wont be able to use the device for development.

Comment: What is "iOS Deployment Target" option in target Build Settings for, in this case? I thought it allowed to specify custom SDK for building the project. Does not it? xCode 4.1 have about 20 different SDK installed beginning from 3.0 and finishing at 4.3.5 (8L1)

Comment: Deployment Target indicates the lowest iOS version you want your app to support. For instance, if you set Deployment Target to 4.0, then devices on 3.1.3 and below are not supported and your app will not install on those devices.

Comment: So the solution can be to install iOS 4.3 for example on my iPhone?

Comment: i believe there is no 4.3 for 3G((

Comment: No, the iPhone 3G is only supported up to iOS 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you disabled any launchdaemons?

If you disabled an accessory launch daemon then I'm guessing it could affect xcode connecting to the device.

Comment: yeah, I'bve disabled several features such as multitasking and wallpapper support for perfomance issue. could it affect? what kind of daemon are you talking about? can I launch it manually? I have ssh root access to my iPhone.

Comment: those arent the daemons im talking about - i was talking about things like usbmuxd or accessoryd daemons, which are enabled unless manually disabled

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Un-Jailbreak it.

Comment: it's risky for me. my iPhone is locked for AT&T, so I can only update it with custom iOS image (without updating modem).