# Xcode 4.2 iOS 5 SDK iPhone 3G not working?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I know that there are a lot of iPhone 3G / xcode4.2 questions on here but mine is strange;

I have XCode 4.2 w/iOS 5 SDK on my Snow Leopard macbook. I already tried changing the architectures and the required device capabilities, but the real problem is my iPhone will not provision.

In XCode i get the error " Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC002)
No such file or directory, at ‘/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-867/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit_Utilities.m:864’"

According to other questions I installed iOS 3.0/3.2.2 and iOS 4.0-4.1 debugging support but even after rebooting I still get the aforementioned error.

[a screenshot of organizer/error http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/3960/screenshot20111227at913.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/3960/screenshot20111227at913.png)

Is there anything I'm missing?

If it would make a difference (i doubt) I'm doing jailbreak development. However I had the same error before I tried JB dev.

Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that this has only recently become an issue for me, even back on Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.3 and the `iOS 5 SDK` it deployed fine. It would appear support was dropped for 4.2.1 along with the transition to Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar to this one: [Jailbroken iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1 can't be debugged with XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432886/jailbroken-iphone-3g-with-ios-4-2-1-cant-be-debugged-with-xcode)
You need a non-jailbroken device to collect debug symbols. After this you can use your device without any problems.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I've moved on from the 3g (it was so slow any way) and am just using my iPod. I'll pick this as the best answer, and even though I didn't get to try it it sounds reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

xCode doesnt support 4.2.1 , restore your device back , or test on a device other than 4.2.1 , 4.2 would be ok

Comment: This is a bad answer, but down voting it will hurt me more. I've built successfully with XCode 4.2 for iOS 4.2.1 numerous times